# Removing SQL injection in following query in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to secure the following SQL query through Parameters, but I am not getting same functionality.

Original SQL query:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY.* FROM ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY where " + cond;
```

After using Parameters,

```
String strQuery=SELECT ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY.* FROM ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY where @cond;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@cond, cond);
//blabla...
```

We are getting the value of `cond` through function call.

Can anyone suggest how to remove SQL injection in this type of query?
Is there any other way of securing this type of query?

**cond** is defined as:
***cond=Condition()***
and Condition() is defined as follows:
We are using cond as follows :                         `cond=Condition();` and Condition function is defined as follows :         public String Condition()

```
{
    string condStr = " 1 = 1";

    if (ddlCountry.SelectedValue != "" && ddlCountry.SelectedValue != "0")
    {

        condStr = condStr + " AND [Country] = '" + ddlCountry.SelectedValue + "'";
    }

    if (txtBatch.Text != "")
    {

        condStr = condStr + " AND [BATCH] = '" + txtBatch.Text + "'";
    }

    if (txtpid.Text != "")
    {

        condStr = condStr + " AND [PARTNER_PRO_ID] = '" + txtpid.Text + "'";
    }

    return condStr;


}
```

Comment: What is in `cond`? How does your complete sql query looks? How is the function that gives you `cond` working?

Comment: _"We are getting the value of cond through function call"_ Don't concatenate your sql in different methods. That's the root of your sql injection problem.

Comment: You have to make the function return list of key/value pairs each is field name and the value, then add each as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to achieve sth like this:

```
var cond = "A = 'A' AND B LIKE 'C'";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY.* FROM ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY where " + cond;
```

**It's wrong approach**. You should rather build something like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY.* FROM ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY where A = @aCond AND B LIKE @cCond;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aCond", "A");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cCond ", "C");
```

It doesn't suffer from SQL injection.

If you want to use variable amount of where conditions, you should build query via string builder with placeholders and then use parameters. Ex

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "A", "B"}, { "A", "C"} };

var lastParam = 0;

var builder = new StringBuilder("SELECT ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY.* FROM ASP_USER.TRANS_MASTER_EMEAPAY where ");

var sqlBld = new SqlCommandBuilder();

foreach (var pair in values) 
{
    lastParam += 1;
    var column = sqlBld.Quote(pair.Key); // if column name is const, you can skip quote
    builder.AppendFormat("{0} = @{1} ", sqlBld, lastParam); // REMEMBER for including OR or AND after clasule.

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(lastParam.ToString(), pair.Value);
}
```

Waning: code has been written from memory, so it can contain errors :)

Of course, you don't have to use dictionary - you could built own structure with - for example - operators.

Comment: I have updated the main code and you can see how i had defined the **Condition()** function in the **cond=Condition();**

Comment: Well, I think my solution is still sutibale for you. Let `Condition()` return `IDicitionar<string, object>` where key is column name. Then build query as above (with query builder and parameters).

Comment: Can you provide me any solution for my case? Actually , I am not getting what you are doing in the **for** loop and how to implement your solution in my project.Please Help.

Comment: How to provide AND or OR conditions while appending to the query? Thanks.

Comment: And what does sqlBld.quote() work?Any help ,will be appreciated.

Comment: I'll try to prepare proper solution for your case in a couple days - I'm out of the home town currently with limited access to the notebook. To provder OR or AND you could prepare triple: <columnName, value, operation> where operaion is f.e. enum of OR, AND members. If it is going about quote (from msdn): _This includes correctly escaping any embedded quotes in the identifier._ It's additional protection for sql injection (you cant f.e. pass table name as command parameter).

Comment: Thank u very much.Can u provide me exactly,what will be the sql query after the first loop? That will be very helpful